# Tabularray table when is wraped by a tcolorbox spreads inside right margin overrides page borders. How can I fix it?

Tags: tables, margins, tcolorbox, tabularray

Please consider the following code. The tables below are exactly the same. One is wrapped by a `tcbbox` of `tcolorbox` package. As you can see, it spreads inside the right margin, breaking page margins. The other one which is not wrapped has the right size. This happens when using an X type column in `tabularray`. How can I fix this without changing the type of X column? I include page frames for better visualization. It seems to me that the indentation length of left margin is added to the right, probably by `tcolorbox`? When the wrapped table in not under any question or subquestion which means left margin indentation is zero it does not spread to the right margin.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={150mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
        \item  This is question 1
        
            \tcbox[left=0mm,right=0pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm]{%
                
                \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
                    text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                    text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                    text in cell 31 & text in cell 32 \\
                \end{tblr}}\hfill
        
                \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
                    text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                    text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                    text in cell 31 & text in cell 32 \\
                \end{tblr}\hfill
        
            \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
                \item Sub question 1
                
                    \tcbox[left=0mm,right=0pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm]{%
                        
                        \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
                            text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                            text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                            text in cell 31 & text in cell 32 \\
                        \end{tblr}}\hfill
            
        \item  This is question 2
                
                        \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
                            text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                            text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                            text in cell 31 & text in cell 32 \\
                    \end{tblr}
                \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\tcbox` creates

> a colored box which is fitted to the width of the given ⟨box content⟩.

It doesn't make sense to combine this with a X column which tries to stretch a column to fit a table to the outside `\linewidth`: The X-column can only stretch after it knows the width of the box, but the box can only know its width after the X has done its work.

Use tcolorbox

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={150mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
        \item  This is question 1
        
          \begin{tcolorbox}[left=0mm,right=0pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm]%               
                \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
                    text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                    text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                    text in cell 31 & text in cell 32 \\
                \end{tblr}
           \end{tcolorbox}     
        
                \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
                    text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                    text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                    text in cell 31 & text in cell 32 \\
                \end{tblr}\hfill
        
            \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
                \item Sub question 1
                
                \begin{tcolorbox}[left=0mm,right=0pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm]%     
                        \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
                            text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                            text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                            text in cell 31 & text in cell 32 \\
                        \end{tblr}
               \end{tcolorbox}         
            
        \item  This is question 2
                
                        \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
                            text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                            text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                            text in cell 31 & text in cell 32 \\
                    \end{tblr}
                \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A temporary solution, I think we can do much better.

Set the width in the `tabularray` environment, removing the `leftmargin` from the `enumitem` environment.

- Get this length in \mylength
  `first=\setlength{\mylength}{\the\leftmargin}` for the first level
- `first=\addtolength{\mylength}{\the\leftmargin}` for the second level
- the boxrule (0.5mm) by default in `tcolorbox`

`\DrawEnumitemLabel` to better see the `leftmargin`

**THE CODE**

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668168/tabularray-table-when-is-wraped-by-a-tcolorbox-spreads-inside-right-margin-overr
    \usepackage[a4paper, total={150mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm,showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \newlength{\mylength}
    \newlength{\myboxrule}
    \setlength{\myboxrule}{0.5mm}%<-- default value in tcolorbox
    \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,first=\setlength{\mylength}{\the\leftmargin}]
        \DrawEnumitemLabel
        \item  \the\leftmargin

            \tcbox[left=0mm,right=0pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm]{%             
                \begin{tblr}{width=\linewidth-\mylength-2\myboxrule,colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
                    text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                    text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                    text in cell 31 & text in cell 32
                \end{tblr}}

            \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
                text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                text in cell 31 & text in cell 32
            \end{tblr}

            \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),first=\addtolength{\mylength}{\the\leftmargin}]

                \DrawEnumitemLabel
                \item \the\leftmargin

                        \tcbox[left=0mm,right=0pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm]{%

                            \begin{tblr}{width=\linewidth-\mylength-2\myboxrule,colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
                                text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                                text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                                text in cell 31 & text in cell 32
                            \end{tblr}}

                \item  This is question 2

                        \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
                            text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                            text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                            text in cell 31 & text in cell 32
                        \end{tblr}
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So the idea is to remove the `\leftmargin` either using `documentclass{article}` and `enumitem` package or `documentclass{exam}` with `\questionshook` or `\partshook`. We cannot define at the preamble our own names for these different lengths which they change throughout the document so they keep them in different names so we could remove them whenever is needed in the `tblr`  environment? Can we do that and how?

Answer (score 1):

Whith the geometry of your document two little change can solve Your problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={150mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
        \item  This is question 1
        
        \tcbox[left=0mm,right=0pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm]{%
            
            \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]Q[8cm,c]},hlines,vlines}
                text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                text in cell 31 & text in cell 32 \\
        \end{tblr}}\hfill
        
        \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[5cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
            text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
            text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
            text in cell 31 & text in cell 32 \\
        \end{tblr}\hfill
        
        \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
            \item Sub question 1
            
            \tcbox[left=0mm,right=0pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm]{%
                
                \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[4cm,c]Q[8.1cm,c]},hlines,vlines}
                    text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                    text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                    text in cell 31 & text in cell 32 \\
            \end{tblr}}\hfill
            
            \item  This is question 2
            
            \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[4cm,c]X[c]},hlines,vlines}
                text in cell 11 & text in cell 12 \\
                text in cell 21 & text in cell 22 \\
                text in cell 31 & text in cell 32 \\
            \end{tblr}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes I already tried this way changing the variable width column X to fixed column Q. But I have to experiment each time with column widths to find the best one. Is inconvenient if you have many wrapped tables. Is there a global way keeping the variable width column X?

Comment: @MiltosP. You have to do this one time for Your document. But if You change the geometry many times...You are right.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoroWhat about if you have many tables with many different column widths?

Comment: @MiltosP. Many different tables, a lot of work more.

Comment: I am looking forward to find a global way with the help of community of course!